# Native library `yoda_phy_pa_x86_64` not found while installing Unet audio in macOS

Tags: unetstack

macOS GateKeeper is giving me the following error message while trying to run Unet audio:

```
"libyoda_phy_pa_x86_64.dylib" cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified
```

and the terminal reads:

```
> bin/unet audio
Native library yoda_phy_pa_x86_64 not found
```

---

Answer (score 2):

1. Once you see the prompt with the message, click "Cancel".
2. Open "System Preferences", and go to "Security & Privacy". The message *"libyoda_phy_pa_x86_64.dylib" was blocked from use because it is not from an identified developer.* will be listed at the bottom part of the dialog with a button saying **Allow Anyway** next to it. Click the button.

[image]

3. Go back to the terminal, type `bin/unet audio` again and press Enter.
4. It will show a dialog with message *macOS cannot verify the developer of "libyoda_phy_pa_x86_64.dylib. Are you sure you want to open it?*
5. Click "open" and that should open a browser window with the **Overview** dashboard of Unet audio.

To install PortAudio:

- Download source from http://files.portaudio.com/download.html
- Build and install instructions: http://files.portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_mac_coreaudio.html
- Alternatively, you can install PortAudio using `brew` by typing the following in a terminal.

```
> brew install portaudio
```

> NOTE: Installation instructions for `brew` can be found here: https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

To install Java 8:

```
> brew tap adoptopenjdk/openjdk
> brew cask install adoptopenjdk8
```

If the following error persists, it might be an issue with the path.

```
> bin/unet audio
Native library yoda_phy_pa_x86_64 not found
```

Brew installs PortAudio at `/usr/local/Cellar/portaudio/` (with symlinks to `/usr/local/opt/portaudio/`). If you installed from source, make sure there is a symlink at the above location to your PortAudio folder.

Answer (score 0):

IF you have mac M1, then you have to change the architecture to x86_64 as JAVA 8 requires intel architecture(first install rosetta 2). \n
To change the architectures -
env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh --login //arm to intel
env /usr/bin/arch -arm64 /bin/zsh --login //intel to arm
you can check by typing % arch
after this install homebrew, JAVA 8 and portaudio as instructed above by @manuignatius.
Then you are good to go.